2007 suburban ltz transmission pan bolt stripped
Hello guys ive never posted on a forum but im stumped i purchased a transmission from summit racing for my 07 suburban and one of the pan bolts is stripped on inside threads and just keeps spinning id like to explore the helicoil method but im unsure as which helicoil kit would be the right fit for the job if anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated
